# batch find and replace files in Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm converting my video library from H.264 to H.265 to save space. However all my files are in a file structure which I want to preserve. I'm encoding all files using Adobe Media Encoder, but it cannot preserve the folder structure - only output the H.265 files into a single folder.

How do I afterwards batch search for an exact file name (xxx.mp4) in a folder structure and then replace it with the new H.265 file (also called xxx.mp4) from a single folder ?

I have 1000+ videos so manually won't work :-)

Any terminal commands that can help?

Comment: Storage is nearly free nowadays - is it really worth it?

Comment: Hey Mark. yes for sure it did - thx. I now get the list out as you described. I still need to test the mv functionality using a few videos before moving to the whole video lib.

Answer (score 0):

I am very reluctant to go around making wholesale changes to thousands of videos on your Mac, so I have done 99% of it here. Please make a backup before you do anything else at all.

Ok, warning over. Save the following file in your HOME directory as `go`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change this to match the top-level of where all your videos are stored
VIDEOLIB="$HOME/path/to/my/videos"

shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

# Loop through all mp4 files in the current dorectory
for video in *mp4; do

   # Get this file's inode number (unique id)
   inode=$(stat -f "%i" "$video")

   # Now find a friend with same name but different inode number
   friend=$(find "$VIDEOLIB" -name "$video" \! -inum $inode)

   if [ -z "$friend" ] ; then
      echo "ERROR: $video has no friend"
   else
      echo "$video is friends with:"
      echo "   $friend"
   fi
done
```

Then start Terminal, and make the script above executable - only necessary once:

```
chmod +x $HOME/go
```

Now change directory to where the **Adobe Media Encoder** has stored its output files, e.g.:

```
cd "path/to/Adobe Media Encoded files"
```

And run the script using:

```
$HOME/go
```

It should run through all the h265 encoded videos and find a matching file for each. It doesn't actually do anything except tell you the matches, you will need a line like

```
mv "$video" "$friend"
```

around 3 lines from the last line and above the line with `fi`... but do your backup and then see if all looks good first.

Comment: Before anyone tells me, I concede that this is not the most efficient design in the world (running `find` for every single video) but it should be easy to understand, robust and plenty fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but maybe someone needs it, here's how I did it:

create a file.sh and put this in:

```
find /path/to/file/folder_01 -name '*.mp4' | while read f; do
  f2=$(find /path/to/folder/folder_02  -name "${f##*/}")
  [[ $f2 ]] && cp "$f" "$f2"
done
```

Then using terminal run:

```
cd file/location 

bash file.sh
```